# How to add Dynamic Headers in retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am trying add dynamic header of a network request. But it got error like **NullPointer**. I tried this way.

```
public interface ApiInterface {

@Multipart
@POST("/api/v1/me")
Call<LoginResponse> completeProfile(@Header("Accept") String accept, @Header("Authorization") String token,
       @Part("username") RequestBody username, @Part("full_name") RequestBody full_name, @Part("email") RequestBody email);
}
```

After i call it this way, i got no values in response .sometimes i got error. I attach my successful request on postman as picture. Can guide me where i am missing something.

```
try {

            ApplicationData.hideKeyboard(activity);
            showProgressDialog();
            RequestBody _name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), name);
            RequestBody _user_name = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), user_name);
            RequestBody _email = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), email);
            RequestBody _home_town = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), home_town);
            RequestBody _date_of_birth = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), date_of_birth);

            ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.completeProfile(ApplicationData.ACCEPT, ApplicationData.AUTHORIZE +
                    "" + ApplicationData.token, _user_name, _name, _email, _home_town, _date_of_birth);
            call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

                    hideProgressDialog();
                    LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();

                    // got crash here null pointer
//                    LogMe.e("response",":"+loginResponse.getMessage());
                    goToHomeActivity();


                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    LogMe.e(TAG, t.getMessage());
                    hideProgressDialog();
//
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.getMessage();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
```

Postman : response well along with this data in picture[image]
**Update:**
Body part of the postman
 [image]

Comment: can you please send screen for a Body part in your postman.

Comment: Please use this code and try to get why are you getting error.

 if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null ) {
           goToHomeActivity();
 }else {
           Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: "+response.message());
 }

Comment: one thing I can't understand that even if you are not passing any File in request body then why you are using `@Multipart` in your interface.

Comment: Try Header Map instead of header and check once. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-dynamic-request-headers-with-headermap

Comment: Use HeaderMap and PartMap to easy code and put each value by checking value != null

Comment: @Anonymous i am trying your guide.

Comment: @shihab_returns...Okie try and let me know k

Comment: @Anonymous still not works.

Comment: @MehulKabaria i added the body part with another image

Comment: Dude where are you sending the profile photo file?

Comment: @Anonymous in this query , doesnt has profile photo

Comment: @shihab_returns but in body you have photo file no?

Answer (score 1):

This blog post is showing how you can add a dynamic amount of request headers to your Retrofit requests.

This is a new feature of Retrofit 2.1, so make sure you've updated your app before you try it out.

[Dynamic Request Headers with @HeaderMap](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-dynamic-request-headers-with-headermap)

Comment: My base url is https://live.********.com so is there any additional requirement i needed

Comment: May be no need anything else. You can also use dynamic URL if you need.
If base is fixed then use default.

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
Call<LoginResponse> completeProfile(@Header("Accept") String accept, @Header("Authorization") String token,
   @Part("username") RequestBody username, @Part("full_name") RequestBody full_name, @Part("email") RequestBody email);
}

Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.completeProfile(ApplicationData.ACCEPT, ApplicationData.token, _user_name, _name, _email, _home_town, _date_of_birth);
```